# A five word answer

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

First word:

> phdnoxba
>   usbjdidgd
>   zbskbdkd
>   ztwicdud
>   levidhdiw
>   ibekdvjdb
>   negeujxy
>   gziwbido

Second word:

> (fgnpx)

Third word:

> egnahcxe

Fourth word:

> vehxhvwjzvbsisvjshzgishshizvsu|is|gdhisvejdjdbjdj

Fifth word:

> amma azza inni gg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First word-

> Puzzling (acrostic spells it)

Second word-

> Stack (Rot13)

Third Word-

> Exchange (Reverse)

Fourth Word-

> Is (hidden between two bars)

Fifth Word-

> Amazing (two letter Acrostic)

Comment: Well done! You've solved it!

Comment: @RohitJose I might just do one of these puzzles one day! I really liked this one! :D

Comment: yah, i liked it too..